# Texturing a Sphere in libGDX

Tags: opengl, android, libgdx

I created a sphere (planet) with a texture (earth texture) in Blender, and exported it using the G3DT exporter. Then when I go to use it in my application I convert to the G3D binary format, and load my texture. When I render my sphere each face contains the texture. It is not wrapping around my whole sphere like it was in Blender. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem ended up being the way that Blender exported my model. I changed the export to just a .obj and re-created my model following [this guide](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/BlenderModels) and everything is mapping correctly now.

Comment: The important difference is to use UV coordinates. You probably did not UV-Unwrap your sphere in blender but use one of the generic texture mappings. This only works in blender because blender generates the UV coordinates for you. OpenGL requires your mesh to provide UV coordinates, because that is the way graphics cards work, so you have to set them in blender manually. I don't know actually if there is a way to export the generated UV coords or if you have to use the unwrap tools.

Comment: @opatut I am pretty sure that was exactly what my problem was. It seemed to work once I made sure to unwrap it and map the image manually in the uv/image mapping window.